# CSS automatically disappearing from Content Editor web part

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I'm adding some css in content editor web part on my aspx page and css applies well but as soon as I stop editing page css disappears. When I open the web part again I can see empty

```
<style> </style>
```

tag. Any idea ?

This page has custom web part and even if I add some inline css to the web part it applies when page loads but disappear when page finish loading..

I'm trying this on Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content editor web part does not let you embed style and script elements directly in the page.

Instead, content editor web part lets you link to a css or js source stored in a sharepoint library.

Alternatively, use SharePoint Designer (if installed in your company) to inline style and script.

Comment: But there are lots of post on net which suggests css method to hide quick launch bar etc ? @Amadeus

Comment: My existing code works fine on other browsers like IE and Safari but don't know why Firefox behaving in such way.

Comment: @Rishi Do you imply that if you navigate to your site **not using any editors**, then the style applies in Safari but not in Firefox?